# How to increase the ResponseBodySize of blob_client.download_blob() (Azure Blob Storage Python SDK)

Tags: python, concurrency, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

Reviewing some Azure Log Analytics logs and I see that each time my Python Azure Function downloads a blob from Azure Storage, there is an initial `32MB` chunk, then all subsequent `GetBlob` actions are `4MB` chunks.

How can I increase this number to reduce the amount of time my Function executes?

**Example Python that downloads blob from storage (Azure Function):**

```
def load_blob_to_memory(blob_client):
    blob_data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
    blob_bytes = io.BytesIO(blob_data)
    return blob_bytes
```

**Example Log Analytics showing ResponseBodySize:**

- Query:

```
//==================================================//
// Assign variables
//==================================================//
let varStart = ago(2d);
let varEnd = now();
let varStorageAccount = 'stgtest';
let varIngressContainerName = 'cont-test';
let varFileName = 'test.csv';
let varSep = '/';
let varSampleUploadUri = strcat('https://', varStorageAccount, '.dfs.core.windows.net', varSep, varIngressContainerName, varSep, varFileName);
let varSampleDownloadUri = replace(@'%2F', @'/', replace(@'.dfs.', @'.blob.', tostring(varSampleUploadUri)));
//==================================================//
// Filter table
//==================================================//
StorageBlobLogs
| where TimeGenerated between (varStart .. varEnd)
  and AccountName == varStorageAccount
  //and StatusText == varStatus
  and split(Uri, '?')[0] == varSampleUploadUri
  or split(Uri, '?')[0] == varSampleDownloadUri
| summarize 
  count() by OperationName,
  TimeGenerated,
  UserAgent = tostring(split(UserAgentHeader, '(')[0]),
  FileName = tostring(split(tostring(parse_url(url_decode(Uri))['Path']), '/')[-1]),
  DownloadChunkSize = format_bytes(ResponseBodySize, 2, 'MB'),
  StatusCode,
  StatusText
| order by TimeGenerated asc
```

- Output:

```
6/9/2021, 6:24:22.226 PM    GetBlob azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10  test.csv    32 MB   206 Success 1   
6/9/2021, 6:24:22.442 PM    GetBlob azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10  test.csv    4 MB    206 Success 1   
6/9/2021, 6:24:22.642 PM    GetBlob azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10  test.csv    4 MB    206 Success 1   
6/9/2021, 6:24:22.780 PM    GetBlob azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10  test.csv    4 MB    206 Success 1
```

There is a `max_concurrency` [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#download-blob-offset-none--length-none----kwargs-) for the `download_blob()` method of `BlobClient` class, but I'm not sure if it requires full async/await rewrite of the code.

**EDIT 1:** Thank you @Guarav. This increased the default to `32MB`.

```
def create_blob_client(credentials):
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(
                      event.get_json()["blobUrl"], 
                      credentials, 
                      max_single_get_size = 64*1024*1024, 
                      max_chunk_get_size = 32*1024*1024
    )
    return blob_client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at `max_single_get_size` and `max_chunk_get_size` arguments of [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python) constructor. You can tweak these two to increase the amount of data downloaded in a single request.

From the documentation:

> **max_single_get_size**
>
> The maximum size for a blob to be downloaded in a single call, the
> exceeded part will be downloaded in chunks (could be parallel).
> Defaults to 32*1024*1024, or 32MB.

and

> **max_chunk_get_size**
>
> The maximum chunk size used for downloading a blob. Defaults to
> 4*1024*1024, or 4MB.

Comment: Something like **EDIT 1:** above?

Comment: I haven’t tried it but it looks all right to me. Can you try by running this code?

Comment: Worked great! Thank you for pointing me to the docs. I wonder what a safe upper value is? `64MB`? `128MB`?

Comment: It seems there's no upper limit to it. I looked up the source code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/7c4cfe236d113c59e66515b6315def256219aa6b/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_shared/base_client.py#L406) and only thing it is doing is setting the default value (32 MB and 4 MB respectively). So I guess it would depend on the network speed and max buffer size.

Comment: I'm using 100MB at the moment. Might experiment with some higher values and see what happens. This one adjustment reduced function execution time by a LOT.

Comment: Awesome! Please share your findings.

Comment: Setting both values to `1024*1024*1024` or  `512*1024*1024` crashed `blob_bytes = io.BytesIO(blob_data)`. I'm novice with Python, so there is likely some way to set the buffer size in `io.BytesIO()` to help this, but I can't quite determine how. There is a `DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` property, but it seems to inherit from somewhere else rather than be settable. So far, going with `max_single_get_size =256*1024*1024` and `max_chunk_get_size = 128*1024*1024` is working well.